# Prevent a specific source file from being generated when using openapi-generator

Tags: c#, .net, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I'm using openapi-generator to generate a C# client SDK against an Open API definition. I use "mustache" template files to customize the generated code. There are some predefined auto-generated source files, however, that I don't need and I would like to prevent them from being generated.

**Is there an option that would allow me to, say exclude a specific source file like for example:**

> "-ignore OpenAPIDateConverter.cs"

Thanks for any insight.